# Recursos en una API RestFul

Tags: api, restful

He leído varias cosas sobre API's pero hay alguna cosa que no me ha quedado claro en el tema de como estructurar los recursos (endpoints). Voy a poner un ejemplo fácil pero ilustrativo. Imaginamos que tenemos esta relación:

```
|Clientes| (1:1) ------<>----- (0:M) |Pedidos| (1:1) ------<>------ (1:1) |Estados|
```

Un cliente puede tener cero o muchos pedidos y cada pedido tiene un estado.

La pregunta viene al hacer los recursos, los recursos que se ven claros son los siguientes:

```
GET /clientes (obtener un listado de clientes)
GET /clientes/10 (obtener el detalle de un cliente)
POST /clientes (crear un cliente pasando los datos por el BODY)
```

(podría haber más como el de `PUT` pero para simplificar el ejemplo simplifico.)

La pregunta es, ¿Para obtener los **Pedidos** de un **Cliente** como sería el `recurso`?

```
GET /clientes/10/orders
```

O en su lugar:

```
GET /orders?id_cliente=10
```

Lo mismo para obtener el detalle de un **Pedido**, ¿como sería?

```
GET /clientes/10/orders/10
```

O simplemente tendría sentido hacer esto (en el cual también saldría la información del **Estado** que tiene):

```
GET /orders/10
```

O en el tema de eliminar un **Pedido**.

```
DELETE /orders/10
```

o en su lugar:

```
DELETE clientes/10/orders/10
```

O tener un recurso que sea simplemente:

```
GET /orders
```

Y sacar todos los pedidos de la base de datos

Y para crear un **Pedido**, debería de existir siempre el **Cliente** o se podría crear un **Pedido** y un **Cliente** a la vez con el siguiente recurso? Por ejemplo, un **Cliente** no registrado al hacer una compra haga el **Pedido** y se registre a la vez)

```
POST /orders
```

Pesándole los datos del **Cliente** en el `BODY` como irían los datos del **Pedido**. Primero se crearía el **Cliente** y luego el **Pedido**.

Si hay alguien que sepa como quedaría todos los recursos válidos de la relación de ejemplo estaría bien que las compartiera. No me quiero meter en temas de Paginación u otros temas que también son importantes en un API. Solo en el tema de recursos.

Answer (score 1):

muy buena tu pregunta, la cual te proporcione la solución a una de tus preguntas (Dado que las demás son muy parecidas)

**1.¿Para obtener los Pedidos de un Cliente como sería el recurso?**

Depende de la implementación de tu [JSON](https://www.json.org/) (Mensaje Body de respuesta), lo cual dentro del objeto clientes puedes tener una Lista de pedidos, como la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "Nombre": "Diego Orellana",
    "Cliente": 1
    "Pedidos": 
        [
            {
                "Descripcion": "Bebida",
                "Cantidad": 1,
                "Precio": 1.00,
                "Moneda": "$"
            },
            {
                "Descripcion": "Hamburguersa",
                "Cantidad": 1,
                "Precio": 2.00,
                "Moneda": "$"
            }
        ]
}
```

Tal como se observas, al llamar **GET /clientes/1** , te traerá un cliente, y dentro de ellos los pedidos correspondientes del cliente (Un cliente puede tener Muchos pedidos).

Cabe mencionar que este es un ejemplo, debido  que depende de la lógica de negocio que implementas en tu aplicación.

Así mismo  dentro de un API, puede implementar varios controladores (Por ejemplo TraerOfertasDelDía(int día), lo cual podrías llamar de la siguiente manera:

> /ofertas/TraerOfertasDelDía?día=1

Lo cual te recomiendos que leas un poco de Implementación de API (Debido que es un extenso tema, y puedes realizar muchas cosas, entre ellos tocarás el tema de Data Transfer Object (DTO), lo cual va muy relacionado a los JSON).

Para finalizar con la respuesta, para borrar un cliente sería de la siguiente manera:

> DELETE /clientes/1

Espero haberte ayudado un poco, saludos.